# Learning resources for Data Engineering

Tags: sql-server, informatica, talend

I recently started my career as Data Engineer, with everyday I explore the dynamics of field and get to know something new. I want to ask if there is any dedicated website, courses or learning path(s) available online to learn this relatively new field.

Note: Let me know if I have asked this question on wrong stack and guide me the correct platform to ask help on this question.

Comment: Is everything on-premises, or are you using any cloud platform?

Comment: mostly things on-prem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure there are more. Feel free to add.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/dp-203?tab=tab-learning-paths
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/dp-203?tab=tab-instructor-led
- https://www.pluralsight.com/paths/microsoft-exam-dp-203-data-engineering-on-microsoft-azure
- https://www.linkedin.com/learning/topics/data-engineering
- https://www.linkedin.com/learning/paths/become-a-data-engineer-mastering-the-concepts